# Hibernate não cria tabela no workbench mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

Tô estudando Spring com hibernate, mas a tabela não está sendo criada no db, não acontece erro nenhum, só não cria a tabela.

*APPLICATION PROPERTIES*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/api_spring\u200B;create=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

*PRODUTO APPLICATION*

```
package com.example.produto;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ProdutoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProdutoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

*PRODUTOMODELO*

```
package com.example.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="produtos")
public class ProdutoModelo {
    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="codigo")
    private int codigo;
    
    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;
    
    @Column(name="valor")
    private double valor;

}
```

*POM XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>produto</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>produto</name>
    <description>API de produtos utilizando Spring</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score -2):

O projeto utiliza, além do Hibernate, o Spring Boot.
A seguinte linha...

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Informa para o spring-boot excluir/desativar a autoconfiguração de DataSource. Com isso, as propriedades definidas no application.properties que iniciam com "spring.datasource" não são tratadas. Sem uma configuração de DataSource, o Hibernate/JPA não pode ser inicializado corretamente.

Remova a configuração de exclusão(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) do @SpringBootApplication , revise os tutoriais nos quais você está se baseando para criar o projeto e verifique se as tabelas do Hibernate são criadas.

Comment: Eaee, então, mesmo assim nao foi kkkk.